# How to Update specific row on Mysql Database based textfield input without using an ID in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this database:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w96Kl.png)

The database in picture have only `CASE_KEY` and `DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER` column, and it doesn't have an `ID`. What I want to accomplish is to update my database using a `TextField.Text` without using `ID` but the problem is I don't know what to put in my Sql Command `WHERE` clause, because the database doesn't have an `ID`. Note I am not allowed to put an `ID` column. This is what I did so far. Please comment what are the alternatives I can use. Thank you.

**CODE**

```
     connect.Open();
     command.CommandText = "UPDATE TV_LABCASE SET DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER = @departmentCaseNumber WHERE //This is my problem";
     command.Connection = connect;

     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmentCaseNumber", txtDepartmentCase.Text);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `CASE_KEY` and the `DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER` are unique together, that is your `ID`

You could do something like this:

```
 connect.Open();
 command.CommandText = "UPDATE TV_LABCASE SET DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER = @newDepartmentCaseNumber WHERE CASE_KEY = @caseKey AND DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER = @oldDepartmentCaseNumber";
 command.Connection = connect;

 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newDepartmentCaseNumber ", txtDepartmentCase.Text);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseKey", variableThatContainsThisInfo);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldDepartmentCaseNumber", variableThatContainsThisInfo);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that I did change the `departmentCaseNumber` into `newDepartmentCaseNumber`